# How to use mat-list-option in mat-selection-list indirectly in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have grouped list of authority, to improving ux using mat-expansion-panel for each group to make groups collapsible. But when checked some options mat-selection-list doesn't change.
This is html file:

```
<mat-selection-list *ngIf="!formProperty.root.schema.readOnly" #list [(ngModel)]="selectedAuthority"
                                        (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let key of objectKey(groupedAuthorities())">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title matSubheader>
                    <h3 translate>app.{{key}}.home.title</h3>
                </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-list-option [value]="authority" *ngFor="let authority of groupedAuthorities()[key] ; let i = index;">
                <p AuthorityTranslate>
            {{authority.name}}
                </p>
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</mat-selection-list>
```

When i clicking on a checkbox selectionChange($event) is calling, but selectedAuthority is an empty list. While if mat-list-option sit immediately after mat-selection-list selectedAuthority contains checked options.
This is selectionChange function in .ts file

```
public selectionChange(authorities: IAuthority[]): void {

    this.formProperty.setValue(authorities, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you're type casting event of type MatSelectionListChange to IAuthority[].

```
(selectionChange)="selectionChange($event.source.selectedOptions)"
```

This will return SelectionModel, you still have to convert it to IAuthority[].

For reference: https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList